# Coding Custom Contrasts

Tags: r

I'm looking to create a user-defined contrast on my data. In brief, the data is organized in a dataframe, with each row having 1 of 4 possible conditions, a proportion of correct answers on a test, and 2 variables called "Schedule" and "Cluster." The head of my data looks like this:

```
  Subjects Condition        PC    Schedule Cluster
1        1         1 0.5555556 Interleaved Similar
2        2         1 0.3425926 Interleaved Similar
3        3         1 0.7129630 Interleaved Similar
4        4         1 0.5000000 Interleaved Similar
5        5         1 0.6296296 Interleaved Similar
6        6         1 0.6851852 Interleaved Similar
```

There are two main contrasts I want to run. The first compares condition 1 to the mean of conditions 2, 3, and 4. The second compares condition 4 to the mean of conditions 2 and 3. I coded my two contrtasts like this:

```
contrast1 = c(1, -1/3, -1/3, -1/3)
contrast2 = c(0, -1/2, -1/2, 1)
```

I then put them into a matrix:

```
cond.contrasts = matrix(c(contrast1, contrast2), ncol = 2)
```

Per advice I saw elsewhere, I got the general inverse of this matrix with a function from the `MASS` package, `ginv()`:

```
cond.contrasts = t(ginv(cond.contrasts))
show(cond.contrasts)
      [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.75  0.0000000
[2,] -0.25 -0.3333333
[3,] -0.25 -0.3333333
[4,] -0.25  0.6666667
```

Note there are only two contrasts here. However, my output looks like this:

```
    lm.experiment = lm(PC ~ Condition, PC)
    summary(lm.experiment)
    Call:
    lm(formula = PC ~ Condition, data = PC)

    Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
    -0.22099 -0.12069 -0.00926  0.11443  0.35117 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.5438470  0.0136786  39.759   <2e-16 ***
Condition1   0.0263110  0.0312175   0.843    0.401    
Condition2   0.0279084  0.0335882   0.831    0.408    
Condition3  -0.0007032  0.0276090  -0.025    0.980    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1472 on 112 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.01234,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.01412 
F-statistic: 0.4663 on 3 and 112 DF,  p-value: 0.7064
```

If I'm understanding this right, my contrasts should be represented by the "Condition1" and "Condition2" coefficients. However, I have no idea what "Condition3" refers to. If I ask R to show me the contrasts directly, it gives me this:

```
> show(contrasts(PC$Condition))
   [,1]       [,2]          [,3]
1  0.75  0.0000000  8.326673e-17
2 -0.25 -0.3333333 -7.071068e-01
3 -0.25 -0.3333333  7.071068e-01
4 -0.25  0.6666667 -2.498002e-16
```

Where does the third column come from? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: How do you set the contrasts for `Condition`?

Comment: You've got four means that are estimable in the model, so you should provide 4 linearly-independent contrasts, even if you only care about two of them.

Comment: @AndrewM Could you explain why that's the case? Thanks!

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Oops, thought I included that!

    `contrasts(PC$Condition) = cond.contrasts`

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the contrasts outside the `lm` function, R will automatically use the maximum number of contrasts. In your example, one contrast is added since 4 factor levels allow for 3 orthogonal contrasts.

However, you can use the parameter `contrasts` in `lm` to override the default behavior. In this case, the specified contrast matrix is used. No additional contrasts are added.

The command:

```
lm(PC ~ Condition, PC, contrasts = list(Condition = cond.contrasts))
```

This means that you want to use the contrast matrix `cond.contrasts` for the factor `Condition`.